# how to move one object and snap this object of center pivot to another?

Tags: snapping

I'm a blender freshman.I'm curious how to move one object and snap this  object of center pivot to another?

Comment: “Object of center pivot”?

Answer (score 1):

This is described in detail on the Blender manual in [Scenes & Objects -> Objects -> Editing -> Snap.](http://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/snap.html) You can also download the manual for free on its index page.

Comment: Hi ZargulTheWizard, thank you   for your sharing.

Comment: Hi ZargulTheWizard, thank you   for your sharing, and it was solved finally.
I move the cursor to  the  center pivot of object  , and then move another object by "selection to cursor".

Comment: @Kenny I believe what you are calling “Center Pivot” is the object’s origin

Comment: @Kenny Anyway, glad it’s solved. 